# Changing Text Inside Logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text

I am very new to design and I want edit the text of an logo which is white and translucent PNG image, so all I want to know is what is the proper way to do that in Illustrator.

For the ones who are interested, this is the icon (You may not be able to see it here because, as I said, it is white and translucent):

> [image: Icon]

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd place a black/dark background behind the logo so we can see whats going on without having to copy paste it into an image editor

Comment: Editing a PNG with Ilustrator is like editing a Word document with MS Paint. Look for a better suited tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the type tool, click on "Culinary" or "Simply great food" and then edit the text. You cant edit the text if these are outlines.

**EDIT:**

In the case of a PNG it is harder to do. You could try image trace, find similar fonts and retype the words as needed.

For the warped text go to edit > enveloppe warp after you typed them, this way you can edit the warp as needed as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the logo is an PNG image

Comment: In that case it is much harder to do. You could try image trace, find similar fonts and retype the words as needed. For the warped text go to edit > enveloppe warp after you typed them

Comment: Thanks for your help @JVS, if you can create an answer containing those tips I will gladly accept it :)